# Primefaces return object of Command Link

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I am trying to invoke the primefaces commanlink via javascript and want to know whether it executed successfully or not and if it is successful i need to get the values which sent by callbackfunction. I am capturing the return value of the commandlinke which is a bunch of javascript. How to get the args(topicComment) value in my senario. I think i can do a workaround by setting few more hidden fields, but i want to see how to get it directly.

**Javascript**

```
$('.postButton').livequery("click", function (){
        var comment_content = $(this).parent().siblings().children('textarea').val();
        $('#topic_comment').val(comment_content);
        var object=$('#postCmdLink').click();
        var output;
        for (property in object) {
              output += property + ': ' + object[property]+'; ';
            }
            console.log(output);
}
```

**Server side**

```
public void addComment(){
        .................................
        context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addCallbackParam("topicComment", topicBean.getTopicCommentVO().getTopicCommentGuid());
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clicking `CommandLink` by jQuery:

```
var object=$('#postCmdLink').click();
```

Uses Primefaces AjaxAPI to call ajax and register a callback to get the result:

```
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest({
         formId:'userForm'
         ,source:'userForm'
            ,process:'userForm'
         ,update:'msgs'
         ,params:{
            'param_name1':'value1',
            'param_name2':'value2'
         }
          ,oncomplete:function(xhr, status, args) {alert('Done');}  
        });
```

Primefaces User documentation 3.1.1 section `7.2 Ajax API` page 454.

Comment: this what i needed i guess. How can i retrieve the params which i sent via AjaxRequest from the JSF Bean?

Comment: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("paramName");`

Answer (score 0):

INMO

if you want to make sure that `p:commandLink` was *executed successfully* just place some js code in the `onsuccess`

something like this

```
<p:commandLink onsuccess="alert('yes!')" id="myId"....
```

Comment: i also need to get key value which is stored as args.topicComment. Is there anyway i can hack the Primefaces.ab({....oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args)}) and get the values from args?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you want to do with the returned value, but you can access it in JavaScript using an oncomplete.

Backing bean:

```
public class TestBean
{
    public void test()
    {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("name", "value");
    }
}
```

JSF:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{testBean.test()}" oncomplete="test(xhr, status, args)" value="test" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(xhr, status, args)
    {
        if (args.name)
        {
            alert(args.name);
        }
    }
</script>
```